# better to select an element and traverse it to find specific offspring children or to assign css class to the children we want to find?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm new to frontend and my question is the following: I have a list of items and I want to remove the last item in some conditions. And it seems to me that there are two options: 1. assign the list with a class, so that I can identify the list by JS and get its child and remove. 2. assign those items with a class, so that I can target the item directly and remove.  To me the drawback of 1 is we are not able get the item directly and the the drawback of 2 is we will assign class to too many element. I'm not able to find related best practice, can anyone point me what docs I should take a look or which one is better and why? Thanks

Comment: The former if there's a ton of items and/or are added dynamically.

Comment: I agree with @zer00ne, and it should then be easy to access the last item using pure CSS like `document.querySelector(".listClassName:last-child")`. There are plenty of other CSS pseudo-classes to help you select a child item without having to parse them with JS (`last-child`, `nth-child`,...) You can check out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes#tree-structural_pseudo-classes).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.